# WebStorm Karma configuration Run vs Debug

Tags: karma-runner, webstorm

Is there a way to know in WebStorm if I'm running karma-runner in Run or Debug mode? I have to apply different configs to make things work. It looks like command line parameters are the same for both mode:

> D:\Tools\nodejs\node.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 11.0.3\plugins\js-karma\js_reporter\karma-intellij\lib\intellijServer.js" --karmaPackageDir=D:\MyFolder\MyProject\app\node_modules\karma --configFile=D:\MyFolder\MyProject\app\karma.conf.js

Maybe I can distinguish mode using environment variables but I can't figure out which one.

Comment: the command used to start server is indeed the same. But WebStorm attaches javascript debugger to http://localhost:9876/base URL that allows to debug karma tests

Comment: what is your use case? do you need to detect current mode programmatically, or?

Comment: well, my karma configuration depends of a complex build routine which generate my files needed to include and other stuff. For an unknown reason, the first time I boot up my karma server, the tests fail. I just have to rerun them and everything is fine. I thought that something was broken but it looks like the build routine isn't over and this is way it fails...